# Saliency maps of neural networks (using Keras)

Tags: neural-network, theano, deep-learning, keras

I have a fully connected multilayer perceptron trained in Keras. I feed it an N-dimensional feature vector and it predicts one out of M classes for the input vector. The training and prediction is working well. Now I want to analyze what part of the input feature vector is actually responsible for a particular class.
For example, lets say there are two classes `A` and `B` , and an input vector `f`. The vector `f` belongs to class `A` and the network predicts it correctly - the output of the network is `A=1 B=0`. Because I have some domain knowledge, I know that the entire `f` is actually not responsible for `f` belonging to `A`, only a certain part inside `f` is responsible for that. I want to know if the neural network has captured that. Drawing a correspondence to images, if an image `I` has a `cat` in it (with some grassy background) and a trained network predicts that correctly, then the network must know that the entire image is actually not a `cat`; the network internally knows the location of the `cat` in the image. Similarly, in my case, the network knows what part of `f` makes it belong to class `A`. I want to know what part that is.

I searched around, and believe what I want to do is called finding Saliency Maps for my network, for a given input. Is that correct?
If I've understood it correctly, Saliency Maps are simply `(change in output)/(change in input)`, and can be found by simply 1 backpropagation operation where I find the derivative of output with respect to the input.
I found the following code snippet for doing this in Keras, but I'm not really sure if it is correct:

```
   inp = model.layers[0].get_input()
   outp = model.layers[-1].get_output()
   max_outp = T.max(outp, axis=1)
   saliency = theano.grad(max_outp.sum(), wrt=inp)
```

In the above code, when computing the gradient, is the backpropagation actually happening? The output is a non-linear function of the input, so the only way to find the gradient is to do backprop. But in the above code, there is nothing to connect `theano` and the network, how is theano "aware" of the network here?  As far as I know, when computing gradients with Theano, we first define the function in terms of input and output. So theano has to know what that non-linear function is. I don't think that is true in the above snippet..

**Update:** The above code doesn't work because I have a fully connected MLP. It gives an error saying "Dense object doesn't have get_output()" . I have the following Keras function, which computes output of network given input. I want to now find gradient of this function wrt the input:

```
    get_output = K.function([self.model.layers[0].input],[self.model.layers[-1].output])
```

Comment: Which version of Keras do you use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
    get_output = theano.function([model.layers[0].input],model.layers[-1].output,allow_input_downcast=True)
    fx = theano.function( [model.layers[0].input] ,T.jacobian(model.layers[-1].output.flatten(),model.layers[0].input), allow_input_downcast=True)
    grad = fx([input_feature])
```