# Why do you have to reshape inputs in Keras/Tensorflow 2?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have a simple network:

```
input_layer = Input(1)
inner_layer = Dense(4, activation='relu')(input_layer)
output_layer = Dense(1, activation='linear')(inner_layer)
model = Model(input_layer, output_layer)
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse')
```

Intuitively, inference for input `0` would simply be `model.predict(0)`. However this generates this error: `expected input_2 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape ()`

I understand it expects the input (which is a single number) to be two dimensional, but I don't understand what Tensorflow accepts as valid input. I tried many different combinations of inputs, some work and some don't, it seems quite inconsistent and the warnings/error are usually not useful:

### When calling `model.predict()`:

- `model.predict(0)` - Throws
- `model.predict([0])` - **Works**
- `model.predict([[0]])` - **Works**

### When calling `model()` (I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58474218/6104191) that's needed to get the gradients):

- `model(0)` - Throws
- `model([0])` - Throws
- `model([[0]])` - Throws

### When using `np.reshape`:

- `model(np.reshape(0,[1,1]))` - **Works**
- `model(np.reshape([0],[1,1]))` - **Works**
- `model(np.reshape([[0]],[1,1]))` - **Works**

What seems to be working consistently is using numpy's `reshape` function. it always works both for `model.predict()` and for `model()` on all the inputs as long as they're reshaped to a `[1,1]` shape.

### My questions:

1. What are the guidelines to feeding inputs into tensorflow models in regards to inputs shapes/types?
2. What does "`shape ()`" mean?
3. What does "`(None, 1)`" mean?
4. Why does `reshape` work but `[[0]]` does not? Both create a 2-dimensional collection.
5. Why when calling `model(0)`/`model([0])`/`model([[0]])` does this warning show: `WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32) for input (None, 1), but it was re-called on a Tensor with incompatible shape ()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shape of the tensor `inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(1)` is `(None, 1)` (run `inputs.get_shape().as_list()`). The `None` means any size that is determined dynamically (batch size). The `1` is the shape of your data point. For example, this is a tensor of shape `(3, 1)`:

```
[[1], [2], [1]]
```

This is a tensor of shape `(3,)`

```
[1, 2, 1]
```

If you define a tensor of shape `(None, 1)` you must feed the data of same shape.

The `[[0]]` has correct shape `(1, 1)` and won't throw any error or warning if you pass it as numpy array of expected data type:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(1)
inner_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')(input_layer)
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(inner_layer)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(input_layer, output_layer)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse')
print(model(np.array([[0.]], dtype=np.float32)).numpy()) # [[0.]]
print(model.predict(np.array([[0.], [1]], dtype=np.float32))) # [[0.        ]
                                                              # [0.08964952]]
```

`np.reshape()` works because it automatically converts your list to numpy array. For more about `np.reshape` refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

The `model.predict()` also expects the same shape as `model.__call__()`, but can perform automatic reshaping (expands dimension on the left, i.e `[1] -- > [[1]]`).