# How to compute gradients w.r.t weights in tf.keras and logging the same for gradients monitoring on tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard, tf.keras, generative-adversarial-network

I'm actually working on basic GANs using TF keras, here I use **train_on_batch** method for training generator and discriminator alternatively which has no **callbacks** parameter for writing tensorboard logs as like **fit** method of keras model. Now I want to write logs of model during training for monitoring weights and gradients on the tensorboard.

The training code part is as follows,

```
def train(g_model, d_model, gan_model, dataset, latent_dim, seed, n_epochs=100, n_batch=128):
  bat_per_epo = int(dataset.shape[0] / n_batch)
  half_batch = int(n_batch / 2)

  for i in range(n_epochs):
    for j in range(bat_per_epo):
      # Training discriminator with real images
      X_real, y_real = generate_real_samples(dataset, half_batch)
      d_loss1, _ = d_model.train_on_batch(X_real, y_real * .9) # Label Smoothing

      # Training discriminator with fake images
      X_fake, y_fake = generate_fake_samples(g_model, latent_dim, half_batch)
      d_loss2, _ = d_model.train_on_batch(X_fake, y_fake + .1) # Label Smoothing

      # Training generator with latent points
      X_gan = generate_latent_points(latent_dim, n_batch)
      y_gan = ones((n_batch, 1))

      g_loss = gan_model.train_on_batch(X_gan, y_gan)

      if not j%10:
        print('>%d, %d/%d, d1=%.3f, d2=%.3f g=%.3f' %(i+1, j+1, bat_per_epo, d_loss1, d_loss2, g_loss))

    display.clear_output(True)
    print('>%d, %d/%d, d1=%.3f, d2=%.3f g=%.3f' %(i+1, j+1, bat_per_epo, d_loss1, d_loss2, g_loss))
    summarize_performance(i, g_model, d_model, dataset, latent_dim, seed)

  display.clear_output(True)
  print('>%d, %d/%d, d1=%.3f, d2=%.3f g=%.3f' %(i+1, j+1, bat_per_epo, d_loss1, d_loss2, g_loss))
  summarize_performance(i, g_model, d_model, dataset, latent_dim, seed)
```

Some of the ways for calculating gradients I've found is here,

1. [How to obtain the gradients in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51140950/9079093)
2. [Getting gradient of model output w.r.t weights using Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39561560/9079093)

But I'm confused with this and how to log the gradients without callbacks option. Can someone please help me on this?