# How can I get input gradient in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I'm building a custom neural network implementation. I use Keras for testing to make sure that gradients computed by my implementation match Keras gradients. Thanks to this answer [How to obtain the gradients in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140950/how-to-obtain-the-gradients-in-keras) I was able to compare weights and outputs gradients. However I would also like to compare gradients for INPUTS. My Keras model is just one dense layer.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(output_size,
                use_bias=bias,
                input_shape=(input_size,),
                activation=activation_name))
model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss=loss_function_name)

...

model.evaluate(x, y)
```

How can I get gradients in respect to `x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to get the gradient of the loss function with respect to the input (not the weights, as is usually the case). You can use `tf.GradientTape()` to achieve this particular task. Here is a sample implementation I referenced from a [TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/adversarial_fgsm), with minimal edits to code to suit your situation:

```py
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy() # Can be any loss function

model = tf. keras.applications.MobileNetV2(include_top=True, weights='imagenet') # Can be any model

def compute_gradient(input, input_label):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(input)
    prediction = model(input)
    loss = loss_object(input_label, prediction)
  gradient = tape.gradient(loss, input)
  return gradient
```

For more information on how to use `tf.GradientTape()`, refer to the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape).