# How to get gradients from GradientTape

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, gradienttape

I wanted to get the gradients from the gradient tape so in tf version 1 I used something like -

```
grads = model.optimizer.get_gradients(model.total_loss, model.trainable_weights)
symb_inputs = (model._feed_inputs + model._feed_targets + model._feed_sample_weights)
```

Now for tf v2 I want to get gradients so I used -

```
grads = tf.GradientTape(model.total_loss, model.trainable_weights)
symb_inputs = (model.feed_inputs + model.feed_targets + model.feed_sample_weights)
```

It is not working, I got errors like feed_inputs or feed_targets are not there.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi @D.L I wanted to get gradients something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140950/how-to-obtain-the-gradients-in-keras

Comment: Closing this as I solved this issue.